# Ext Toolbar items listerners not working in overflow menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a Ext.toolbar.Toolbar with few buttons and a controller that listens to click event of these buttons like this

```
    control({    
          '#button1id': {
             click: this.handler1
           } 
    });
```

Problem is  enableOverflow is set to true in the toolbar and whenever there is overflow, the buttons which become part of the overflow menu - their ids and even itemids change and so controller listeners are not working.....Whats the best solution for this ?

Comment: Strange thing is if I add enableToggle: true for a button , its id doesn't change in overflow menu item and this listener works.....But I can not do that for every button

Answer (score 1):

Try not using ids if you know the button might go into the overflow.
Use some other custom option like:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    action: 'foo', // custom option
    text: 'whatever'
}
```

Then set your controller like this:

```
control({    
    '[action=foo]': {
         click: this.handler1
    } 
});
```